# Expressions of month

Tags: sentence-construction, time-words

I am always confused with those expressions of month. Below I will list some of the expressions I can think of.

Please correct me and tell me what is the most common one.

1. In early / mid / late January
2. In  ***the*** early/ mid / late January
3. early this year
4. in ***the*** early of this year

Which one is correct between:

> I applied for the driving licences early this month.

and

> I applied for the driving licences in early April.

Answer (score 3):

Neither is correct :) But not because of the reference to the month. You're using "the driving licences", which is plural, but you (an individual) cannot apply for more than one. "My driving licence" is more correct, although "my driver's licence" is more common (here in Canada anyway).

About the months, both "early this month" and "early April" are fine. However, if today is still in the month you are referring to, it is more common to say "earlier this month".

You would not say "in *the* early January", since you would never say "in *the* January".

Comment: Both *driving licence* (UK) and *driver's license* (US) / *licence* (CA) are correct.

Comment: True, but you probably still wouldn't say "the licenses" no matter what country you're in, no?  You're usually only getting one, which would make it singular, and *a* license, not *the license*.

Answer (score 1):

I would write them as follows:

> 1 : in early / mid / late January
>   2 : in *the* early / mid / *latter part of* January
>   3 : early this year OR in the early *part* of this year

4 : Either one is correct. *license* should be singular though, unless you are getting more than one of them..

Comment: after ur explanation I have a clearer understanding, thank you !